# ASP.NET Event rasied on back button of browser

Tags: asp.net, events

I have an asp.net page_load event.
When the user clicks the back button of the browser I want to set some values in the page_load event.
The problem is that when I click on the back botton the page is rendered from Cache and the page load event is not fired.
What should I do so that page_load gets fired ...other than forcing the browsers cache to clear ?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't mess around with the back button. It belongs to the user's browser, not to your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution.
Indeed the back button has nothing to do with the server events...the page is directly renedered from the browser cache.
So what I did was that I ran a script on the page load but not ASP's page load ,rather the javascript page load.
Whenever the back button is clicked the JS page load would be raised.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you have the following situation:

- User visits page A.
- User clicks a link and visits page B.
- User clicks the back button and page A is displayed again. It is displayed from the browser cache, instead of being refetched from the server.

Is that right? In that case you should mark the page as no-cache. With the [`Response.CacheControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524721%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property you can decide what caching options are returned in the http header of the response.